# When does freeze action happen in java constructor?

Tags: java, concurrency, memory-visibility

I am confused about final field semantics in java. I've read 17.5 paragraph jls and found this example:

```
class FinalFieldExample { 
    final int x;
    int y; 
    static FinalFieldExample f;

    public FinalFieldExample() {
        x = 3; 
        y = 4; 
    } 

    static void writer() {
        f = new FinalFieldExample();
    } 

    static void reader() {
        if (f != null) {
            int i = f.x;  // guaranteed to see 3  
            int j = f.y;  // could see 0
        } 
    } 
}
```

The JLS states that there is no guarantee that we will see `4` in reading `f.y`. And it also says next:

> It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.

I don't understand this.
Imagine that we have the following code:

```
public FinalFieldExample() {
        ar = new int[n]; // ar is final var
        ar[0] = 1;
    }
```

Does it mean that we have guarantee that other thread will read array with 1 at first position?
I heard yes.
And I've read that `freeze action` happens when we write to a final variable, but why we can read array with correct elements? (I found out it in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/final-keyword-and-jvm-memory-impact).) Writing to final field happens before writing to array's first element.

And if it is true, why in first example(with `x` and `y`) we don't have guarantees to see 4 in y?

And my final question is:
Does freeze action happen at the end of constructor(during reference publication) or after each write to a final field?

I've read this [article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/all-fields-are-final/)  but didn't find example with 1 final and 1 non final writes in constructor. Alexey says that synthetic freeze happens at the end of constructor. Does it mean that we will see correct values in reading from non final variables initialized in constructor? Is writing to final variable enough to see writes to other non final variable?

Comment: Only the value, in this case a reference to an array, of the final field is fixed. The *contents* of the thing being referenced is not fixed.

Comment: @Bohemian But in this specific case, for `final` variables, yes, they are.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Does it mean that in first example we are guaranteed to see 4?

Comment: No, as `y` isn't `final`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Hmm, and if writing to array’s element is reordered with reference publishing by JIT or CPU? Can they do this?

Comment: Immediately under [that code example in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#d5e38815) is the text “One thread might execute the method `writer` and another might execute the method `reader`.”  That special circumstance is entirely the point of the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The JLS states that there is no guarantee that we will see `4` in reading `f.y`.

Yes, if one thread invokes `FinalFieldExample.reader()` and another invokes `FinalFieldExample.writer()`, with nothing to establish a happens-before relationship between these, then the program is not properly synchronized, and its behavior is undefined.  In particular, it is possible for the thread invoking `reader()` to observe a partially-initialized state of  `FinalFieldExample.f`.

> > It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are.
>
> I don't understand this.

A field whose type is a reference type -- a class, interface, or array type -- stores a *reference* to an object (or `null`), not the object itself.  The spec is saying that all writes to the referenced object that happened before the assignment of the final field's value will be visible to any thread that observes the field's (initialized) value.

> Imagine that we have the following code:
>
> ```
> public FinalFieldExample() {
>         ar = new int[n]; // ar is final var
>         ar[0] = 1;
>     }
> ```
>
> Does it mean that we have guarantee that other thread will read array
> with 1 at first position?

No.  The assignment to `ar[0]` happens *after* the assignment to final variable `ar`.  It is not guaranteed that a thread that can observe the object in a partially-initialized state must read `1` from `ar[0]`.

> Does freeze action happen at the end of constructor(during reference publication) or after each write to a final field?

The term "freeze" in this context refers to visibility guarantees related to the completion of the constructor.  That has nothing to do with the fact that the constructor can assign each otherwise uninitialized final field only once, or with the other visibility guarantee you asked about.

Comment: Thank you bro! And can I fix array initialization by creating temp local variable in constructor, set 1 to temp’s first element, and then set temp to global variable, will it help?

Comment: @РоманГригорьев, that would enable you to leverage the first visibility guarantee you asked about instead of having to rely on the second, but that's all moot if you avoid premature publication of references to your class.  Which is absolutely what you should do.

Comment: The key point that is missing from this, @РоманГригорьев, is that if you ensure you don't 'premature publish', `ar = new int[1]; ar[0] = 1;` __does mean__ that it is __impossible__ to observe `ar[0]` being 0 outside of the constructor. John Bollinger said 'no' because of premature publishing. Which is allowing code outside the constructor to 'see' the ref. For example if you write in your constructor: `System.out.println(this);`, `println` now gets a ref to the object halfway through construction. The freeze hasn't happened yet, no guarantees yet. But, the simple solution is: Don't pre-pub.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Oh, yep, I missed it. I didn't say that I guarantee no escaping of `this` from initializing constructor. My bad.
Eventually, I have understood next from your answer. If we guarantee no escaping of this reference from constructor, and if we have final variable initializing in constructor, even if it has type of array and we put elements to it after assigning value to final object's field, after constructor end(freeze action) we will see actual value of it with elements we have put to it in constructor. I am right?

Comment: @rzwitserloot Also I have found this article : https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#:~:text=A%20final%20field%20was,field%20in%20the%20course. Where Alexey says we will see all values after constructor ends if we have at least 1 write to final variable in it. But...why jls doesn't guarantee it, it stands opposite(example with x and y)

Comment: @РоманГригорьев Yes, you are right.

Comment: @РоманГригорьев, the author of that article calls that an "implementation quirk", and that seems an apt characterization.  The JLS does not require any such behavior, and (therefore) it is not safe to rely on Java implementations to behave as described without first verifying by code review, careful use of a debugger, or similar.